# Prove the identity $\binom{2n}{2}$ = $\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{n-2}+n^2$ where $n\geq2$ using a combinatorial proof.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

Prove the identity $\binom{2n}{2}$ = $\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{n-2}+n^2$, where $n\geq2$, using a combinatorial proof.

I've tried to think of it in terms of a counting problem. I think that for the left hand side that given a group of people of size 2n you'll be choosing 2 people out of that. I think that the right hand side may be breaking down the left hand side into cases, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've tried to think of it in terms of a counting problem. I think that for the left hand side that given a group of people of  size $2n$ you'll be choosing 2 people out of that. I think that the right hand side may be breaking down the left hand side into cases, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please edit the question to include this information, and briefly mention in what context you are trying to solve this problem. If you do, I'll upvote your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Split the $2n$ elements into two halves of size $n$. What are the possible ways $2$ chosen elements can be distributed between the halves? How many ways are there to choose them consistently with each distribution?

Comment: I think I understand where the $\binom{n}{2}$ and the $n^2$ come from, but I'm not sure about the $\binom{n}{n-2}$.

Comment: @ivyleaf57 Since choosing $k$ items out of $n$ is the same as (not) choosing $n-k$ out of $n$, we have ${n \choose 2} = {n \choose n-2}$. Either choose two items left, choose two items right or choose one from both sides.